# Tcl - Save regexp result into a variable

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to do the following:

Take the `<body>` tag and store in a variable.
`<body>` tag may not be string `<body>`every time, but `"\<body bgcolor="somehex" blah="blah"\>`

I want to capture the entire body tag via regex and save it into a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the backslashes weren't meant to be in the actual html string.

```
regexp -- {body[^>]*} $html bodytag
# -> 1
set bodytag
# -> body bgcolor="somehex" blah="blah"
```

Documentation: [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [Tcl regular expression syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: You may also want to point him to the documentation for re_syntax since tcl regexp is not the same as perl regex which is not the same as javascript regexp

Comment: @slebetman: good point. This exact expression seems to work in php, python, ruby, javascript, and perl as well, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like as below.

```
set html {<body bgcolor="somehex" blah="blah"\>}

#The first sub-match will hold the tag content and will be saved in the variable 'body_content'
#The variable 'all' will hold the whole content including the body tag itself

# The flag '-nocase' causes case insensitive match
if {  [ regexp -nocase {<body\s+(.*)\\>} $html all body_content]  } { 
    puts $body_content
} else { 
    puts "No match found"
}
```

Please note the use of `\s+` and `\\` where the former one matches the spaces and later one took care of the closing body tag. You can customize the `regexp` if you would like to manipulate any further.

Comment: No, that's too greedy. What if `set html {<body bgcolor="somehex" blah="blah"\><h1>hello world</h1\>}`